# Running a single spark for all pytest cases

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pytest

I have a folder structure as below /test

```
----test_abc.py
----test_bcd.py
 ----test_cde.py
----conftest.py
```

conftest.py contains all spark-initiation items and in each pytest file, I use these fixtures.

For executing all pytest files, I am writing a shell script that will call all tests as shown below. Is this the correct way? I think if I call these files individually as below, it will initiate a new spark session every time I execute. Is my assumption right, Can I use the same spark session for all pytests?

**bashscript.sh**

```
pytest ./tests/test_abc.py --emr 
pytest ./tests/test_bcd.py --emr 
pytest ./tests/test_cde.py --emr
```

Comment: You’re correct that this will create a separate pytest session for each call, and all session-scoped fixtures would only persist through the duration of each of the pytest calls. So if you had a session-scoped spark fixture, it would be created three times in the above setup. Any reason why you don’t want to just call `pytest`?

Comment: How to call just pytest?   something like this?
pytest ./tests/test_abc.py --emr ,  ./tests/test_bcd.py --emr , ./tests/test_cde.py --emr

Comment: Or just `pytest .  --emr` (Or `pytest tests  --emr` if you want to limit the session scope to the tests dir, but often this isn’t the case)

Comment: if i do pytest . --emr , it willl execute all files in the current folder, I want only 3 files to execute rest can be ignored

Comment: Ok. You can list the files too if you want. I don’t know what emr is but I expect you only need to pass it once.

Comment: ok let me try, thx]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a single pytest session but only call a few files, you can pass them in as positional arguments to pytest:

```bash
pytest ./tests/test_abc.py ./tests/test_bcd.py ./tests/test_cde.py --emr
```

In this way, session scoped fixtures will only be created once.